# Too many files for Assets to display

Tags: assets

I have Assets hooked up to S3, and have over 35,000 images indexed. When loading the Assets module file manager, the browser clocks and cannot render the file list. Same thing when selecting a file from the Assets field.

Inspecting the Assets source code, Assets_lib::get_folder_tree() is being called, creating one huge array of all folders/files.

Is there any way to lazy load files into the browser? Is there a setting in Assets to do this? Or how do others handle a large quantity of files? Is there a different module that will give me the S3 hookup and still handle a large quality (I am willing to sacrifice UI/design if I can find a solution to this issue).

Any direction would be appreciated, I am planning on using over 200,000 images in the future.

- EE 2.5.5
- Assets 2.1

**UPDATE:** I have over 6,500 folders within my S3 bucket. Although the files are being lazy loaded as noted in the comments, the folders are not - this is where I believe the issue to be.

Comment: I have a situation very similar to this and previous dev resorted to using text input fields and pasting the images one by one which of course isn't very UF.

Comment: Thanks for that - I agree that makes for a very poor experience for the admin; there has to be a way for EE to be able to handle this situation.

Comment: Hey Ben - as you know from email  I've asked our devs to look at this. :) Thank you!

Comment: I've never had a chance to try it though, [Channel Images](http://www.devdemon.com/channel_images/) may be a option.

Comment: Benjamin, get_folder_tree, as the name implies, generates just the structure for folders and it is being used in the sidebar. Files are being loaded after the page renders via Ajax call and are being lazy-loaded 100 at a time - this sounds like a mis-diagnosis and if you email support@pixelandtonic.com, I'd be more than happy to look into to see what's killing it for you.

edit: ah, my bad, just noticed the email.

Comment: Was there ever a resolution to this issue? I'm finding difficulty with Assets as well: I don't have nearly as many images as Ben, but Assets will regularly time out, with the error, "Could not upload the file - server returned an unexpected response. Please check the server settings." I do see the "You have exceeded the allowed page load frequency," warning, but I adjusted those settings...